# Nginx update rewrites my own starting scripts in /etc/init.d/nginx. Is there a way to avoid this?

Tags: linux, centos, nginx, fastcgi, init.d

I have nginx plus fast cgi. I wroted starting script that starts nginx with fast cgi. But after nginx update system rewrites this script to the default starting only nginx. Is there any way to avoid this rewrite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should create a separate init.d script for your fastcgi server and leave nginx one untouched. Take a peek to `/etc/init.d/skeleton`.

Comment: I want to start nginx and cgi together

Comment: So, configure the fastcgi script to be started on the same runlevel of nginx.

Answer (score 0):

Or make it start like this instead of the init.d startup;

```
nginx -c /path/to/your/nginx.conf
exec /path/to/your/start-fastcgi-script.sh
```

put this in /etc/rc.local